# How to concatenate two tuples in DolphinDB?

Tags: tuples, dolphindb

I want to concatenate two tuples in the way similar to concatenating vectors. For example, I have two tuples: `a=(1,2,3)` and `b=(4,5,6)`, and I want to use `join` to obtain `re=(1,2,3,4,5,6)`. However, the output is `(1,2,3,(4,5,6))`, which is same as the result of `a.append!(b)`. How could I modify my script?

Comment: Never used DolphinDB.  What about union? https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/u/union.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` function alone won't return the desired result because it treats the second tuple *b* as a single element. You can use it within the `reduce` function:

```
a1= (0,[1,2,3],4)
a2 = ([5,6], 7)
reduce(join, a2, a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `join` and `union` can not work on tuples. You can try:

1. `flatten((a, b))` to create a new tuple with elements in `a` and `b`;
2. `each(append!{a}, b)` to add every element in `b` into `a`.